# Bounds for the derivative of inverse Mills ratio of standard normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm trying to find bounds for the derivative of the inverse Mills ratio $\lambda(x)=\dfrac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$:

$\lambda^{\prime}(x)=-\lambda(x) (x+\lambda(x))$

While my matlab numerical results suggest that $\lambda^{\prime}(x)\in(-1,0)$, I could not prove that $\lambda^{\prime}(x)>-1$ for any $x$. Any ideas on how to prove it?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1283/erfc-lower-bound/133829#133829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof from [Sampford (1953)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2236360?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents):

Observe that $\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} u^2}}{\int^{x}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2} u^2}\, \rm du}$ is a pdf defined on $(-\infty, x]$ and its variance is given by  $1-\lambda(x)x -\lambda^2(x)$

Thus $1-\lambda(x)x -\lambda^2(x) = 1 + \lambda^{\prime}(x)>0$.